# How to Send a jpeg File from a Folder on Server to the Client and Display It in an Image element?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, fetch, fs

I am using node.js and express server-side. I am using whatwg-fetch and React client-side. What is currently happening is:

Step 1: I use fetch client-side to make a post request to the server.

Step 2: I have the server send back a file indicated by the client. Example:

```
res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/../Images/' + 'ImageTheClientWants.jpeg'));
```

Step 3: I look at the response.body on the client-side and it is of type ReadableByteStream. I am not sure how to proceed from here.

My only thought right now is to read the bytes into a Buffer, turn that Buffer into a string and then if necessary encode that string to base64. 
Then I could setState in react an element like this:

```
<img src={src} />
```

where

```
src="data:image/jpeg;base64," + the_string_I_created_from_ReadableByteStream;
```

My first problem with this approach is that javascript does not seem to have lots of good tools for working with buffers out of the box (unless I am missing something in the docs). My second problem with this approach is that there is probably already some package on npm that does this in a better way and has been tested.

My question is how can I send a jpeg image file (that is not public) to the client and display that image in an html image tag? Am I on the right track or is there another way to accomplish this?

I also just want to note that in general I do not want to make the images public which is why I do not just upload them to the public folder.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this solution,this is the related question [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413689/how-to-open-image-in-javascript-sent-by-express-js-sendfile-functionsolution)

react:

```
<div>    
    <img src={image_src}></img>
 </div>
```

express:

```
router.get('/image/:id',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(dynamicImagepath);
});
```

Comment: I think this is a good answer. This is much simpler and I can still authenticate a user before sending the file. It works for me. Thanks!